# Can I have "and" in more than one clause in a sentence?

Tags: commas, conjunctions

I've read on this site you can have more than one "and" in a sentence, but all the examples used "and" continuously.

> At school today, we had sums and writing and play and dinner and a story and a prayer and then I came home.

I was wondering if correct to use "and" in different clauses within a sentence, or should I separate them with a period instead of a comma.

> Towards the end of my student teaching, I had more students share their problems in life and in the classroom, so it became apparent my work was important to their lives and made a difference.

Comment: The first sentence sounds quite childish and childlike. Kids do speak like that.

Comment: I know, but apparently it a rhetorical device is called polysyndeton.[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysyndeton]

*edit: I am more concerned about the second sentence's grammar.

Comment: No, Mercedes, that would be in a well-written sentence, not some junky sentence like the one  you found on that website. Unless a child actually said it. I suspect the website owner just dreamed it up.

Comment: Adult native speakers wouldn't normally include ***and*** repeatedly like that. Also note that ***to have dinner*** isn't the same kind of thing as ***to have sums / writing / a story***, so stringing those two concepts together in such a syntactically "tight" format is something of a [zeugma / syllepsis .](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis)

Answer (score 2):

> We have peanut butter and ham sandwiches and jam and cheese sandwiches.

This has three, is not complex, and is fine. The rapid fire ands in your first example definitely make the voicing childish.

Answer (score -1):

Towards the end of my student teaching, ||I had more students share their problems in life and in the classroom|| so it became apparent my work was important to their lives and made a difference.

That's fine: a complex sentence with two ands in each. No problem at all.